# An indexed MySQL query performs better with a 1 than a 0

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the following query where `Date` has data-type `non-nullable date-time`, `GroupingId` has data-type `non-nullable int` and `IsCompleted` has data-type `non-nullable tinyint(1)`.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    Date < @TimeNow
AND 
    GroupingId = @GroupingId
AND 
    IsCompleted = 0;
```

I have an index on this table of `GroupingId`, `Date`, `IsCompleted` in that order.

For some reason if I run this query with `t.IsCompleted = 0`, it performs a lot slower than `t.IsCompleted = 1` every time.

I'm thinking that it may not be indexed effectively but could do with some help on it.

EDIT

I've updated the example query to make it a lot clearer.  When `IsCompleted = 0` is set, it returns far fewer rows and takes a lot longer than when `IsCompleted = 1` is set

Comment: You should probably change ordering of columns in index, if you're always using `isCompleted` column to: `groupingId, isCompleted, Date` because equality will discard rows faster than range when scanning through an index. To your particular question check how many rows each query returns when `isCompleted = 0 / 1` and/or review EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: Changing the indexing order didn't work, and when the `IsCompleted = 0` it returns a lot less rows, that's why I'm confused why that version is slower

Comment: Can you post a query plan?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Which it is?  A single comparison on `Date`, as shown in the Question, or an `OR`, as shown in Gordon's reply?  It makes a _big_ difference in optimization!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query cannot use the index for sorting.  So, the performance of the query is going to be driven by the number rows that match the `where` conditions.  Presumably, more items have `IsCompleted = 0` than `IsCompleted = 1`.

The better index for this query is `(groupingId, isCompleted, date)`.  The first two keys can be in either order.

This condition:

```
((t.Date >= @StartDate AND t.Date < @EndDate) OR (t.Date < @TimeNow))
```

is also a bit strange.  I would expect most or all dates to be in the past.  Assuming that `@TimeNow` represents something like the current date, this would return all rows.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer.  It's effectively a table representing a list of tasks that have either been completed or not, and when they are due.  The condition you're confused about allows me to list upcoming tasks in the next week, but also show any overdue tasks

Comment: Also, a lot less rows have `IsCompleted = 0` than `IsCompleted = 1`

Comment: Changing the index order to the one you've suggested no longer even uses that index when I do an explain plan

Comment: @lisburnite . . . Interesting.  What is the impact on performance?

Comment: @lisburnite - Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; there may be extra clues.  Do that for =1 and =0; they could be different.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be datatypes, etc, that give us some clues.

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out though, I added the index solely on the IsCompleted flag as there are very few occurrences of IsCompleted = 0